# Игра велась ПО заведениям и ПО квартирам (см. контекст) - можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> ...Игра <азартная карточная, запрещённая> велась по всяким
>   сомнительным заведениям или даже по частным квартирам, причём место и
>   пароль могли меняться за час до начала.

Comment: Совсем не по-русски. Заменяйте смело "по" на "в".

Comment: Шлю автору немедля! Я закончила чтение большого пассажа.

Comment: @grizzly пожалуйста, не используйте для ответов комментарии.

Comment: @Aer Я постараюсь поступать правильно. Просьба ответить мне на два вопроса (или подсказать, где лучше задать эти вопросы): (а) как лучше поступить в подобном случае — ничего не отвечать или дать такой короткий ответ, не вдаваясь в обоснования? (автор вопроса в данном случае, думаю, советуется, а не требует отсылки к нормативам); (б) как лучше поступить в этой ситуации — переместить комментарий в ответ или оставить как есть? Спасибо!

Comment: @grizzly, а что ты теряешь? Пятёрку за верный вариант я всё равно поставлю, приятно ж.  Но если поступит вразумительный ответ, почему можно оставить как есть, ЛО вручу ему.

Comment: Я не теряю :) Я здесь до сих пор новичок и хочу знать как поступать правильно. (Выше я не просто советовался, а спрашивал правила игры у модератора.)

Comment: Даёшь ответ по делу - получаешь оценки от автора и других заглянувших в ответ (если не жмоты и не новички; ты ж вот ни одной оценочки мне за ВОПРОС не поставил). Растёт репа = репутация. Тебя начнут узнавать и приглядываться... Плюсик за вопрос - 5 баллов, за ответ -10, за ЛО - и сколько проголосует, и 15 от благодарного автора.

Comment: Я неуклюж, безразличен к очкам и сам иногда забываю поставить галочку. Сейчас отметил вопросы, которые мне понравились. PS. Предлагаю не позже чем завтра удалить взаимно эту почти личную переписку :)

Comment: Да ни за что. Она любому новичку понадобится... )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то нашелся пример употребления, по смыслу похожий на ваш:

*Разумеется, у Галича было мало возможностей выступать со своими песнями открыто, и он был вынужден **давать концерты** в основном **по частным квартирам.***
[**М. Аронов. Александр Галич. Полная биография**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=UPZ4BgAAQBAJ&pg=PP228&lpg=PP228&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87&source=bl&ots=JRiVTKjhf4&sig=dlf3zhX_mfH6iLVTZ-qtMwVyf_g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL4pahtY_YAhVOJFAKHeEXA0wQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87&f=false)

А мне кажется, что можно так написать. Ведь всем понятно: "по заведениям, по квартирам" = "в заведениях, в квартирах" (зато нестандартно, необычно).